# AEM 6.5 - AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate request

Tags: java, adobe, aem, aem-6

im always getting this error in my local environment up.

```
HTTP ERROR 503 AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate the request.
URI:    /
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate the request.
SERVLET:    org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet-7eebf294
```

there is a suggestion to remove index files in crx-start/repository folder but it didn't work out for me. not able to access the login page even

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I was able to fix this issue by removing the following folder before starting the instance:

rm -rf crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/org/apache/sling/jcr/repoinit

Comment: In my case all my bundles were up i.e. active and only felix console was working nothing else was opening it showed 503.
Performing above step resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, most likely the instance is corrupted. You can try using the oak-run tool to compact the repository and identify the last good segment: https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/command_line.html

If this is a development environment, it would be quicker to start from scratch.

Comment: i did that too. but still it was failing. then did it from the scratch. im really wondering why it happen and why there is no way to recover it without starting from the scratch which is very time consuming

Comment: There are a lot of possible causes. For example, how are you shutting down the instance? Abruptly killing the process or sudden machine restarts usually corrupt the instance. Is this happening after you install your code? What is the AEM version that you are running and what is the expected AEM version in your project? Is any service pack pending that should be installed before deploying your code?

Comment: I think that's the reason for having this issue I guess. (not shutting down the aem instance correctly). but im looking to recover it instead of a fresh installation. my aem version is 6.5 i have installed the service package before the code installation. it worked fine in 1st then giving this error. maybe due to sudden machine restarts. but there should be a way to recover it right ?

Comment: Yes, but it is harder to recover, it should be better to have a fresh instance and have a proper start/stop script or you can use the built-in on/off when you double click the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by deleting the following:

crx-quickstart/repository/segmentstore/repo.lock

crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix/cache.lock

crx-quickstart/repository/index

crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/org/apache/sling/jcr/repoinit